# Using a namespace as parameter type with Closure Compiler

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-closure-compiler

In my angular project compiled with closure compiler I'm using Firebase (loaded separately). The extern file contains:

```
/**
 * @namespace
 */
var firebase = {};
```

I have some functions which take the whole firebase as a parameter (provided by AngularFire as `"Firebase"`), but I somehow can't annotate its type correctly. The compiler says

```
WARNING - Bad type annotation. Unknown type firebase
 * @param {firebase} Firebase
           ^
```

If I use anything from within, e.g. `firebase.auth` or `firebase.database`, it works, but the object I'm getting is the whole namespace.

How can I make Closure Compiler accept the namespace as type in `@param`, to understand the parameter? Is it a bug or feature? (Is writing a typedef for it a good workaround?)

Answer (score 1):

Closure compiler doesn't support this use case. Namespaces are anonymous types not named types. There is no way to appropriately reference a namespace type in the current type system.

See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/266

Comment: So is this something that will work in the new type system? https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Using-NTI-(new-type-inference)

Comment: No - new type inference can infer the types of aliases, but there is still no way to explicitly refer to the type of a namespace or alias in an annotation.